# Why doesn't `mypy` detect bad TypedDict usage inside a function

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have the following Python module:

```
from typing import TypedDict

class P(TypedDict):
    x: int

def return_p() -> P:
    return {'x': 5}

p = return_p()
p['abc'] = 1

def test():
    p = return_p()
    p['abc'] = 2
```

When I run `mypy` on it, it rightfully complains about the line `p['abc']=1`, but ignores the exact same issue in the line `p['abc']=2`.

This happens on Windows 10, with Python 3.8 and mypy 0.781. The same behavior occurs with Python 3.7 (there I need to import `TypedDict` from `typing_extensions`)

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `test()` is not typed. Adding type hints to its signature will make its body checkable:

```
def test() -> None:
    p = return_p()
    p['abc'] = 2
```